# Latest npm version is not working in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I just updated npm to latest version, but in Linux is not working properly.
When I was trying to install new modules showed errors:

- Cannot find module 'asynckit' or
- Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata' or
- Cannot find module 'har-schema' ...

npm 5.0.1
node 8.0.0

Someone has any idea why it is happening just in Linux (ubuntu 17.04)?
Thank you

Comment: I assume you're using `npm install` or `npm install asynckit`?

Comment: How *exactly* have you updated `npm`? Are you using `nvm` ?

Comment: @robertklep even installing like that, there are others modules with the same error

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs sudo npm install -g npm@5.0.1

Comment: Can you add the full output of a failing `npm install <module>` to your question?

Comment: Also, do you still have update log available?

Comment: AndrejsCainikovs robertklep I don't have more both. I found a solution downgrading to npm 4.6.1, but it will be good if it works in the new one.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`npm` versions 5.0.0/5.0.1 have bunch of install/update related problems, and I do not advise to use 5.x at this moment, unless you're ready to dig into issues and are able to solve them by your own.

Issue [#16833](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16833). Issue [#16877](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16877). Issue [#16901](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16901). Issue [#16907](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16907). Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt-get update
```

Update your system